# React-Native Tab Navigator memory leak due to no component willunmount

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am really confused how to solve the issue of canceling an async process when moving to a new tab. If you start an async request on a page but, then navigate to a new tab before it's complete, you will get the warning: "Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component"

However, changing screens via the tab navigator will never fire the willunmount so, there is no real place to cancel any operations. 
Stack Navigator and switch navigator fire this and I can cancel any operations just fine. I literally am about to build my own bottom nav to get around this.

This sample is way to hacky IMHO:

YES, I've tried the this.isMounted approach (BTW you now will get the isMounted(...) is deprecated warning if you use that) Yes, I've used the willupdate method but, PureComponent is suppose to remove that "hack".

This really feels like a bug to me and I am at lost to how to have a bottom Navigation AND have a page with some fetch results.

// Hacky Example in async method

```
 try {
            let response = await fetch(
                 'https://your/rest/endpoint/with/json'
            );
            if (response.ok) {

                if (!_isMounted) {
                    console.log('oops! ' + SCREEN_NAME + ' was unmounted before async');
                    return; // just bail if component is no longer mounted
                }

                let responseJson = await response.json();
`
```

Comment: are you using redux ?

Comment: Yes same issue as there isn't a place to unsubscribe from redux. Again No unmount

Comment: I tried to explain my point in an answer ... check it out plz

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Redux:

You could move all of your **Async Code** into an **Action** ...

If you're executing your async code in an action instead of executing it inside your component's life ...  it's ok if the user decided to move to a different tab and the **action** has not been resolved yet ((because it's running in a different context than the component's lifecycle)) ... once the action is done and your component is still active >> then it'll receive a new set of props to update itself ...

And regarding setting state on an unmounted component ... you could use this template for any class-based component that has a state:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // other fields...
      isUnmounted: false,
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({ isUnmounted: true });
  }

  setComponentState = (values) => {
    if (!this.state.isUnmounted) this.setState(values);
  };
}
```

Comment: But, that is the issue, it IS getting new props, setState gets fired. The page isn't visible (your on a different tab) and that gives you the warning.

Comment: @wilmsoft yes true ... that warning is a different issue that could easily be solved by applying the template in the answer ... check it out plz

Answer (score 0):

Redux is not wrong but, for my case more complicated than required.

So, if anyone is struggling with React-Navigation Tab Navigator and async fetch. I was able to achieve the pattern I was after (firing an event to be able to cancel async events).

You CAN add a Listener when the screen is navigated to or from (blur)

React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to them:

```
willFocus - the screen will focus
didFocus - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
willBlur - the screen will be unfocused
didBlur - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
```

basically I did this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
console.log(SCREEN_NAME + ' Component Did Mount');

this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', (route) => {
  _isMounted = false;
  this.axiosCancelSource.cancel('Component unmounted.');
});

// didFocus will fire on 1st Mount as well
this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', async (route) => {
  _isMounted = true;
  this.axiosCancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source();     
  await this._getTourList();     
});
 console.log(SCREEN_NAME + ' Component Did Mount Complete');
 }
```

[React-Navtive Navigation props web site](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html)